# Cloudera-Agent giving error - 'Hostname is invalid; it contains an underscore character.'

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I'm trying to setup an HBase cluster on 4 Virtual Machines using Cloudera-Manager installer (as suggested in the installation guide). Cloudera-Manager version is 4.6.1, CDH version is 4.3 and OS is CentOS-6.4. But after the parcels are installed and cloud-era agent tries to start,
following errors are reported : 'Hostname is invalid; it contains an underscore character.' from /usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/agent.py : 315.

I can see an underscore( '_') check in host-name at line 315 of agent.py. Cross-checked our previous setup of CDH3.4 and there was no such validation. Can some-one from the developer/user confirm if the check is relevant and whether underscore('_') is not used internally in CDH code for any parsing logic? Did someone was able to install with underscore in hostname?

Appreciate any input on this issue.

Thanks,

Abhishek

PS : I disabled the check and so the cloud-era agent started and I configured the roles for the various HDFS services on these nodes. But the Services are not coming up healthy. Changing the host-name is not in my hand and have been told that due to some xyz reasons, it'll take time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from [wiki link:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names)

> The Internet standards (Request for Comments) for protocols mandate
>   that component hostname labels may contain only the ASCII letters 'a'
>   through 'z' (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits '0' through
>   '9', and the hyphen ('-'). The original specification of hostnames in
>   RFC 952, mandated that labels could not start with a digit or with a
>   hyphen, and must not end with a hyphen. However, a subsequent
>   specification (RFC 1123) permitted hostname labels to start with
>   digits. No other symbols, punctuation characters, or white space are
>   permitted.

So, having hostnames with _ is illegal, I wondering how did you even setup a cluster with that?

Comment: We have a cluster running successfully on Cloudera-4.0.1 with CDH-3u4 where host-name contains '_' character. So I didn't expected this problem with host-name. As this check has been introduced recently in Cloudera, it's possible that the CDH distribution has stick to the rule. I'll suitably request to adhere to the standard.